# Using Unit of Work with Windsor Castle inside SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, signalr, windsor-3.0

I'm working in an ASPNET MVC 4 project using SignalR and Windsor Castle.
I've mvc controller and WebApi controllers working and instantiating ok with Castle, but my Unit of Work class is not instantiated when it is used inside the Hub of SignalR.

Is there something I'm missing?

This is my code:

**IocConfig class**

```
public static class IocConfig
    {
        public static IWindsorContainer Container { get; private set; }

        public static void RegisterIoc(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Set the dependency resolver for Web API.
            var webApicontainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WebWindsorInstaller());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WebApiWindsorDependencyResolver(webApicontainer);

            // Set the dependency resolver for Mvc Controllers
            Container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new ControllersInstaller());
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MvcWindsorDependencyResolver(Container)); 
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(Container)); 
            var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(Container.Kernel); 
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory); 
        }
    }
}
```

**WebWindsorInstaller class**

```
 internal class WebWindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component
                .For<RepositoryFactories>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryFactories>()
                .LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IRepositoryProvider>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryProvider>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IGdpUow>()
                .ImplementedBy<GdpUow>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Classes
               .FromAssemblyContaining<Api.MessagesController>()
               .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
               .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
               .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        }
```

**ControllerInstaller class**

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(FindControllers().Configure(c => c.LifestyleTransient()));

            container.Register(Component
                .For<RepositoryFactories>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryFactories>()
                .LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IRepositoryProvider>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryProvider>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IGdpUow>()
                .ImplementedBy<GdpUow>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }

        private static BasedOnDescriptor FindControllers()
        {
            return AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IController>()
                .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));
        }
```

**Hub**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

[HubName("iServerHub")]
public class IServerHub : Hub
{
    protected IGdpUow Uow;

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        var messagesList = Uow.UdsMessages.GetAll();       
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(messagesList);
    }
}
```

In the Send method Uow is null.

**Controllers are inherited from this base class**

```
 public abstract class CustomControllerBase : Controller
    {
        protected IGdpUow Uow { get; set; }
    }
```

And when I use Uow in the controller it is instantiated. I don't understand the difference with using it inside the hub.

**NOTE**

I'm following the instruction found here on how to set up Windsor Castle to make it work with SignalR, but I can't test it since I'm getting the following error (seems that the proxy cannot be created):

```
Cannot read property client of undefined
```

meaning that the proxy to the hub was not created

This is how I have it in the server

public class IServerHub : Hub

and like this in the client

var clientServerHub = $.connection.iServerHub;

I can see the dynamically created file here:

/GdpSoftware.Server.Web/signalr/hubs

So, Why the proxy is not created?

**This is my installer file**

```
public class HubsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component
            .For<RepositoryFactories>()
            .ImplementedBy<RepositoryFactories>()
            .LifestyleSingleton());

        container.Register(Component
            .For<IRepositoryProvider>()
            .ImplementedBy<RepositoryProvider>()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(Component
            .For<IGdpUow>()
            .ImplementedBy<GdpUow>()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<Hub>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you expect it to be resolved? I don't see that code.

I don't know ASP.NET MVC very good but last time I used it controllers were receiving dependencies through constructor. How your controllers' ctors look? Do they take IGdpUow as parameter? If not how it is injected? I think Windsor can only inject when you have public setter for property - [Castle Windsor property injection](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=How-properties-are-injected&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

So I guess your controllers have ctors and your IServerHub doesn't (BTW in .NET this name is a bit misleading for a class)

Comment: I'm selecting your answer as the correct one because it pointing me to the correct solution.

I followed the instructions here: http://blog.mirajavora.com/signalr-dependency-injection

Then I removed every instance of using SignalR; and changed it for
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
And added in HubInstaller the content I had in the other installer to instance the unit of work like RepositoryFactories and IRepositoryProvider
That made it work.

Thanks!